# Polymorphic Json Marshalling with Apache Camel

Tags: java, jackson, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm refactoring a camel route to hopefully be a little more generic. (I'm also using spring boot, if that helps for any possible bean injection solutions)

```
from(fromKafka)
                .routeId("Rest Models")
                .removeHeaders("*")
                .aggregate(new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
                .constant(true)
                .completionTimeout(batchingInterval)
                .process(new ListOfJsonToJsonArray())
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, InputArrayPojo.class)
                .enrich("seda:rest", mergeRestResult)
```

the processor `ListOfJsonToJsonArray()` takes the json string representation of the kafka message, and joins everything, comma separated, with a `{[ ]}` on the outside.

The InputArrayPojo.class is thus a wrapper for the array of objects that are coming in from kafka. I need to bundle the objects in order to mini-batch to the REST interface in the enrichment. The objects contained are of format InputPojo.class (effectively just a schema, but also performs some basic data quality checks)

**I need a way to generify InputPojo.class such that for our new jobs, we can run the same route, but supply a different InputPojo.class.**

I've tried to apply polymorphism and create an interface for InputPojo, however this runs into an error when trying to construct the interface.

```
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=InputPojo.class, name = "online")
})
public interface InputPojoInterface {
}
```

I also tried some parameterisation, but I had no luck there either because it would not apply the constructor of the bean, none of the methods then existed.

I've also included

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException - Cannot construct instance of `InputPojoInterface` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: InputArrayPojo["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]
```

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "data"
})
public class InputArrayPojo{

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<InputPojo> data = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<InputPojo> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<InputPojo> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

The enrichment also needs to implement some type of generifying logic

```
@Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

        List<IngestionOutPojo> originalMessages = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(IngestionOutArrayPojo.class).getData();
        List<PredictionPojo> enrichmentMessages = newExchange.getIn().getBody(PredictionArrayPojo.class).getData();
        List<ModelResultPojo> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < originalMessages.size(); ++i) {
            ModelResultPojo output = new ModelResultPojo();
            IngestionOutPojo raw = originalMessages.get(i);
            PredictionPojo enrich = enrichmentMessages.get(i);
            /*
            enrichment logic to create modelResult
            */
            outputList.add(modelResult)
    }
    newExchange.getIn().setBody(outputList);
    return newExchange
}
```

Comment: How does you `InputPojo ` class look like. It should have an annotation `@JsonTypeName`.  See an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-polymorphic-type-handling-annotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming up with a solution by doing the following:

unmarshalled to the default type: Map<String,Object> (without specifying a class, it camel unmarshalls to a Map<String,Object>)

After that I wrote an abstract class that implements a processor. In this processor I take the Map, and apply an abstract editFields() function to the Map.

thus I now have polymorphic handling of business logic through a Map instead of through a POJO.

Comment: Yeah get rid of bean mate. Use the map. So much easier to work with and maintain.